# SQL SSRS aggregate fuctions

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am trying to figure out the aggregate functions in SQL SSRS to give me to sum of total sales for the given information by YEAR. I need to combine the year, the months within that year and provide the total sum of sales for that year. For example: for 2018 I need to combine month's 2-12 and provide the total sum, for 2019 combine 1-12 and provide total sum and so on.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJjh4.png)

I'm not sure where to begin on this one as I am new to SQL SSRS. Any help would be appreciated!

UPDATE:

Ideally I want this to be the end result:

```
id      Year  Price
```

102140  2019  ($XXXXX.XX)

102140  2018  ($XXXXX.XX)

102140  2017  ($XXXXX.XX)

And so on.

your query:

```
 Select  customer_id
 , year_ordered
 --, month_ordered
 --, extended_price
 --, SUM(extended_price) OVER (PARTITION BY year_ordered) AS year_total
 , SUM(extended_price) AS year_total
 From customer_order_history 

 Where customer_id = '101646'

 Group By 
 customer_id
 , year_ordered
 , extended_price
  --, month_ordered
```

Provides this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJjh4.png)

multiple "years_ordered" because it is still using each month and that months SUM of price.

Comment: You are still grouping by extended_price, the grouping should be only by customer and year as per my answer

Comment: ughh sorry I didn't see that! thank you!

Comment: no problem, as long as you get it sorted in the end...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches.

1. Do this in your dataset query:

   SELECT Customer_id, year_ordered, SUM(extended_price) AS Price
       FROM myTable
       GROUP BY Customer_id, year_ordered

This option is best when you will never need the month values themselves in the report (i.e. you don't intend to have a drill down to the month data)

2. Do this in SSRS
   By default you will get a RowGroup called "Details" (look under the main design area and you will row groups and column groups).
   You can right-click this and add grouping for both customer_id and year_ordered. You can then change the extended_price textbox's value property to `=SUM(Fields!extended_price.Value)`

Comment: Number 1 SUM's the price for the month and the year still. it is not adding all 12 months within the year and summing the price. Number 2 I did not think of doing it inside SSRS, I will try this, Thanks!

Comment: All 1. does is sum up everything by customer and year, it ignores months. Can you show your expected output based only on the sample data you posted. I think there is some info you have not provided as this query is as about as simple as it gets.

Comment: Updated with your query and the results

Comment: That is not what I put in the answer. You are grouping by extended_price, remove that from the group by clause

Answer (score 0):

You could use a window function in your SQL:

```
select [year], [month], [price], SUM(PRICE) OVER (PARTITION BY year) as yearTotal
from myTable
```